# Laravel Localized Routes

Tags: laravel

I want to create laravel(5.6) localized routs for example : mysite.com/about - mysite.com/fr/sur

```
Route -> Web.php 

foreach (config('app.locales') as $locale){ //config('app.locales') = ['en','fr']
    $pref = ($locale  != 'fr') ? ['prefix'=>$locale,'middleware'=>'LanguageCheck'] : ['middleware'=>'LanguageCheck'];

    Route::group($pref,function (){

        Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

        Route::get('/'.__('urlabout').'','HomeController@about');



    });
}



Middleware -> LanguageCheck

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->segment(1)){
            session(['locale'=>$request->segment(1)]);
            app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        }else{
            session(['locale'=>'fr']);
            app()->setLocale('fr');
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
```

This way working on mysite.com/about, mysite.com/fr/about but when i try access mysite.com/fr/sur I'm getting the error that the page can not be found.

Any suggestion for localized routes without any package.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Let me suggest you to use this library that does exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: @Jackowski yes, i saw it but i hope i can solve more easy way. If nothing work i think i'll use it. Thanks for suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not necessarily transfer the localization via url, then the best solution is to transfer the localization using Headers Accept-Language. You can get headers in the middleware and display content from the controller depending on what you came up with

Comment: Nope, i need transfer localization/lang  via url :(